# which is better choice to read edi data and convert to java object

Tags: edi, smooks

I am new to edi data. We have the requirement to parse edi data into java object. Smooks is one i found which i tested and works fine. 
Due to lack of documentation, i am not able to decide to directly go for it and start implementing with it.

> I want to know the limitations and shortcomings of smooks?
>
> I have one more question about, Is there any other api/framework
>   available to do the same? If yes, how it is better than smooks?

Thanks